# How to activate multiple ports listening with shell

Tags: shell, port, netcat

I have small scripts that I am using for ports listening and to save all incoming characters in txt files and it looks like this (for every port another .sh file and saving to another .txt):

```
startnc1.sh, startns2.sh etc   
------------------------------
        
#!/bin/bash
            
i=6
while [ $i -le 10 ]
do
    nc -l xxx.yyy.zzz.qqq 12345 >>/home/jack/russel/12345.txt -w 10
done
```

This have worked perfectly until I had to upgrade CentoOS on newer version.
Because of that now I have to periodically reset this scripts and I would like to have another script that doing that automatic.
I tried with this one:

```
startall.sh
------------------------

cd /home/jack/russel
sudo close_port.sh


for start in {1..30}
   do    
      killall "startnc${start}.sh"
   done
killall nc


for start in {1..30}
do
   ./startnc${start}.sh &
done


sudo open_port.sh
```

startall.sh do the job good and in WHM I can see that all processes are started, but nothing is saved in txt files.
Any advice?

Comment: Try `nc -w 10 -l xxx.yyy.zzz.qqq 12345 >>/home/jack/russel/12345.txt 2>&1`. If `nc` is giving errors they will appear in the txt

Comment: Hey LMC, I've tried, but again nothing in the txt

Comment: What's `close_port.sh`, `open_port.sh`?

Comment: Armali, that parts works without problems... that are scripts that opening and closing ports in Firewall